# Can I run java in android studio without the emulator?

Tags: android

I recently started developing for android, and I prefer coding classes, methods first then working around the UI. Is it possible to test/execute the said code in my pc, that doesn't necessarily need an UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my android projects i always have an android app subproject (i.e. [APhotoManager app](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/tree/FDroid/app)) and a java-library subproject (i.e. [APhotoManager fotolib2](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/tree/FDroid/fotolib2)) where the non-android code goes to.

The java-library-subproject can be easily juinit tested outside the emulator or in non java apps (i.e. [APhotoManager fotolib2 tests](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/tree/FDroid/fotolib2/src/test/java/de/k3b) )

Answer (score 0):

[jUnit](https://junit.org/junit4/) unit-tests would run on the localhost; else there is little chance to run anything. it's version [4.12](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.12.md).